# jQueryUI extending Dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, extend, extending

I am trying with the code below to extend jQueryUI Dialog to get to something like this:http://www.schillmania.com/projects/dialog/png/

Everything works fine except the fact that when I click the button to close the dialog nothing happens.

```
(function( $, undefined ) {

    var uiDialogClasses = "ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content roundbox";

    $.widget("custom.mydialog", $.ui.dialog, {

        _super_create: $.ui.dialog.prototype._create,
        _create: function() {
            this.originalTitle = this.element.attr( "title" );
            // #5742 - .attr() might return a DOMElement
            if ( typeof this.originalTitle !== "string" ) {
                this.originalTitle = "";
            }       
            this.oldPosition = { 
                parent: this.element.parent(), 
                index: this.element.parent().children().index( this.element ) 
            };
            this.options.title = this.options.title || this.originalTitle;
            var self = this,
                options = self.options,

                title = options.title || "&#160;",
                titleId = $.ui.dialog.getTitleId( self.element ),

                uiDialog = ( self.uiDialogOriginal = $( '<div class="lbasDialog">' ) )
                    //.addClass( uiDialogClasses + options.dialogClass)
                    // setting tabIndex makes the div focusable
                    .attr( "tabIndex", -1)
                    .keydown(function( event ) {
                        if ( options.closeOnEscape && !event.isDefaultPrevented() && event.keyCode &&
                                event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE ) {
                            self.close( event );
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    })
                    .attr({
                        role: "dialog",
                        "aria-labelledby": titleId
                    })
                    .mousedown(function( event ) {
                        self.moveToTop( false, event );
                    })
                    .appendTo( "body" )
                    .wrap('<div class="dialog"><div class="bd"><div class="c"><div class="s"></div></div></div></div>')

                    self.uiDialog = $('div.dialog');

                     $('div.dialog')
                       .prepend('<div class="hd">'+
                         '<div class="c"></div></div>')
                       .append('<div class="ft">'+
                         '<div class="c"></div></div>')
                       .addClass( uiDialogClasses + options.dialogClass);



                uiDialogContent = self.element
                    .show()
                    .removeAttr( "title" )
                    .addClass( "ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" )
                    .appendTo( uiDialog ),

                uiDialogTitlebar = ( self.uiDialogTitlebar = $( "<div>" ) )
                    .addClass( "ui-dialog-titlebar  ui-widget-header  " +
                        "ui-corner-all  ui-helper-clearfix" )
                    .prependTo( uiDialog ),

                uiDialogTitlebarClose = $( "<a href='#'></a>" )
                    .addClass( "ui-dialog-titlebar-close  ui-corner-all" )
                    .attr( "role", "button" )
                    .click(function( event ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        self.close( event );
                    })
                    .appendTo( uiDialogTitlebar ),

                uiDialogTitlebarCloseText = ( self.uiDialogTitlebarCloseText = $( "<span>" ) )
                    .addClass( "ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" )
                    .text( options.closeText )
                    .appendTo( uiDialogTitlebarClose ),

                uiDialogTitle = $( "<span>" )
                    .addClass( "ui-dialog-title" )
                    .attr( "id", titleId )
                    .html( title )
                    .prependTo( uiDialogTitlebar );

            uiDialogTitlebar.find( "*" ).add( uiDialogTitlebar ).disableSelection();
            //this._hoverable( uiDialogTitlebarClose );
            //this._focusable( uiDialogTitlebarClose );

            if ( options.draggable && $.fn.draggable ) {
                self._makeDraggable();
            }
            if ( options.resizable && $.fn.resizable ) {
                self._makeResizable();
            }

            self._createButtons( options.buttons );
            self._isOpen = false;

            if ( $.fn.bgiframe ) {
                uiDialog.bgiframe();
            }
        },
        _createButtons: function( buttons ) {
            var self = this,
                hasButtons = false;

            // if we already have a button pane, remove it
            self.uiDialogOriginal.find( ".ui-dialog-buttonpane" ).remove();

            if ( typeof buttons === "object" && buttons !== null ) {
                $.each( buttons, function() {
                    return !(hasButtons = true);
                });
            }
            if ( hasButtons ) {
                var uiDialogButtonPane = $( "<div>" )
                        .addClass( "ui-dialog-buttonpane  ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix" ),
                    uiButtonSet = $( "<div>" )
                        .addClass( "ui-dialog-buttonset" )
                        .appendTo( uiDialogButtonPane );

                $.each( buttons, function( name, props ) {
                    props = $.isFunction( props ) ?
                        { click: props, text: name } :
                        props;
                    var button = $( "<button type='button'>" )
                        .attr( props, true )
                        .unbind( "click" )
                        .click(function() {
                            props.click.apply( self.element[0], arguments );
                        })
                        .appendTo( uiButtonSet );
                    if ( $.fn.button ) {
                        button.button();
                    }
                });
                self.uiDialogOriginal.addClass( "ui-dialog-buttons" );
                uiDialogButtonPane.appendTo( self.uiDialogOriginal );
            } else {
                self.uiDialogOriginal.removeClass( "ui-dialog-buttons" );
            }
        }
    });

}( jQuery ) );
```

here is how I do use it:
and the issue seems to be that `$(this).dialog('close');` dose not call the close function at all....

```
    var btns = {};
    btns[$.i18n.prop('buttons.ok')] = function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
    };

    var opt = options || {};

    if(opt.open==undefined)
        opt.open = true;

    $dialog = $('<div class="0m4r"></div>');
    $dialog.mydialog({
        title: opt.title || '',
        bgiframe: opt.bigFrame || true,
        modal: opt.modal!=undefined?opt.modal:glbmodal,
        overlay :{
            backgroundColor :'#000',
            opacity :0.8
        },
        buttons: opt.buttons || btns,
        width: opt.width || $(document).width()/2,
        height: opt.height || $(document).height()/2,
        position: 'center',
        autoOpen: opt.open, 
        close: function(){
            $(this).dialog('destroy');
            $(this).remove();
            $('.dialog').filter(function(){
                if ($(this).text() == "")
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }).remove();
        }
    });


    if(opt.content){
        $dialog.html(opt.content);
    }
    return $dialog;
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are referencing the wrong variable with "this".

```
btns[$.i18n.prop('buttons.ok')] = function() {
    $(this).dialog('close');
};
```

The `$(this)` selector here is selecting the button from your array of buttons, which I don't think is what you are trying to accomplish as your buttons don't have a dialog attached.  You need to reference the dialog itself to close it, something like this.

```
  $($dialog).dialog('close');
```

Comment: This same code that you point out as not working works good with the jqueryui dialog thing, i mean, the original one...